# преобразовать email таким образом: email@mail.ru => e****@mail.ru

Tags: python, строки, email

Мне нужна помощь, как преобразовать email в python таким образом:

```
email@mail.ru => e****@mail.ru
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://ideone.com/V4uotZ
https://ideone.com/LsE3ME

```
s = 'email@mail.ru'
i = s.find('@')

print(s[0] + "***" + s[i:])
print(s[0] + (i-1)*'*' + s[i:])
```

Comment: @insolor, спасибо, исправил.

Comment: Перепишу комментарий. ИМХО, лучший вариант: и кратко, и читаемо. Если честно, вообще почти забыл что можно использовать просто find)

Comment: @insolor, мне тоже нравится. А плюсов почему-то меньше всего у этого варианта :(

Answer (score 3):

```
s = 'email@mail.ru'
parts = s.split('@')
s1 = parts[0][0].ljust(len(parts[0]), '*') + '@' + parts[1]
```

Если нет условия чтобы результат был обязательно той же длины, а просто нужно добавить 4 звездочки в середину, то немного проще:

```
s1 = parts[0][0] + '****@' + parts[1]
```

Еще вариант через f-строки:

```
x, y = s.split('@')
s1 = f'{x[0]:*<{len(x)}}@{y}'
```

Answer (score 2):

https://ideone.com/ndLbOz

```
import re

s = 'email@mail.ru'

print(re.sub('(.).*@', r'\1***@', s))
print(re.sub('.(@.*)|(?!^).', r'*\1', s))
```